# Chrome: A html space is replacing %20 to %2520

Tags: java, android, http, get

I am trying to get the values from a webpage, and to get the values i have put %20 between the different values. But chrome is replacing %20 to %2520 because of which i am not getting correct values.

ex: i am trying to read values of url :

**https://..../place?action=list&&device=359299059228937&q=1110%201113%201175%201114%201115%201116%201111%201117%201123%201452%201112%201121%201120%201119%201122**

and %20 automatically got replaced by %2520 when i press enter.

**https://..../place?action=list&&device=359299059228937&q=1110%25201113%25201175%25201114%25201115%25201116%25201111%25201117%25201123%25201452%25201112%25201121%25201120%25201119%25201122**

I have searched this issue in lots of posts but didn't find my solution.

and when i try reading something with url below:

**https://..../place?action=list&&device=359299059228937&q=1110 1113 1175 1114 1115 1116 1111 1117 1123 1452 1112 1121 1120 1119 1122**

then also it is converting " "(space) to %2520 see below:

**https://..../place?action=list&&device=359299059228937&q=1110%25201113%25201175%25201114%25201115%25201116%25201111%25201117%25201123%25201452%25201112%25201121%25201120%25201119%25201122**

Kindly help.

Comment: My Suggestion, use a different delimiter like a `-`. Or avoid double encoding URI.

Comment: This isn't a Java or Android question. It's not really an http or get question, either -- this is really a Chrome question. That said, I can't repro this, using http://httpbin.org/get?q=a%20b. That page shows the arg `q` with a value of `a b`, which is what I'd expect -- and is different from what it would be if Chrome replaced the `%` with `%25`.

Comment: but it used to run fine earlier.. i dnt know why its not running today @uma

Comment: i have seen that post also but didnt help @Uma

Comment: what should i do now @yshavit

Comment: @Sangeeta I don't know, it's hard to debug with that little info. Are you absolutely sure it's Chrome that's doing the substitution, and not something else (maybe you're encoding a string that's already been encoded)? This seems like something that's happening on the server side of things, not in Chrome.

Comment: you can say that, i am making a url using my android application and when i paste it into chrome i get this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately %25 is the code for the % character and so somehow your %20 is not getting encoded properly. You could try find and replacing the %20 with actual spaces. I know that fix has worked on other occasions.  Otherwise, consider a link shortener as a work around.

Comment: i have tried that also but simple spaces are also being converted into %2520

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to include the %20 in the URL, otherwise it will indeed be replaced with %2520.

What worked for me is to create a URI and set it to contain the desired URL, and then create a URL from the URI. When you do this, do not use %20, use literal spaces. After that, create a URL from the URI, and output the URL using the toExternalForm method.

For example:

```
    URI uri = null;

    try {
        uri = new URI(
                "http",
                "search.barnesandnoble.com",
                "/booksearch/first book.pdf",
                null);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        // The content TextView is what I used to test the output
        content.setText(url.toExternalForm());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This worked for me on Android and Java platforms.

Comment: even simple space also get converted into %2520

Comment: This exact code worked for me. What language and environment are you working in? Could you post some of your code?